# JavaScript Custom event is occuring in a loop after pressing submit button

Tags: gigya

For JS custom event after clicking the submit button on the second progressive profiling screen`event==='afterSubmit'`, this whole event keeps repeating again and again until I close it. I am using `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` to stop this event but it's not working any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I see is that since you are using the afterSubmit event, and calling accounts.showScreenSet inside it, everytime you press submit on the new screen, it will in turn, call the event again. This is probably not wanted behavior.

Secondly, it is better to fire the screen only if the field you are checking is empty, not full. The way it is now means that the screen will always fire if the user has already filled out the field.

You can try this:

```
if (e.eventName === 'afterSubmit') {

                alert('afterSubmit Fired');

                if (typeof (e.profile.zip) !== 'undefined') {
                    if ((e.profile.zip == '') || (e.profile.zip == null)) {
                        alert('Yo 2nd step..');
                        alert('Zip is empty, please fill out your zipcode on the next screen');

                        gigya.accounts.showScreenSet({
                            screenSet: 'New-RegistrationLogin',
                            startScreen: 'Bio'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also, when adding additional information to an existing user's profile, it is recommended best practice to use a screen within the ProfileUpdate screen-set, not the RegistrationLogin screen-set.

Comment: How can i make this code in event after submit run at least once even though there is some value in zip field. the screenset after event aftersubmit should load only once

Comment: Alok, you can see the link below; but basically you would need to create a new boolean field in your site's schema and then you can show the screen only if the value of this field is false or null and once the screen is displayed,  set the field to **true** (also checking if the other field contains data, if that is required). You can see the **Code Example 'Time Since Registration'** on that page for an idea how to set it up. http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Progressive+Profiling#ProgressiveProfiling-BestPractice-GlobalConfiguration